# your credentials did not work (remote desktop, windows 10)

Tags: remote-desktop, credentials

I'm using Windows 10, and I want to connect to another computer using Remote Desktop Connection. It shown "You will be asked for credentials when you connect". Then I need to submit username and password:

[image]

I reinstalled Window, and set my name as User without password. But when I submit only username, it shown the error: the credentials that were used to connect did not work. Please enter new credentials.

[image]

The thing is, before I reset my computer, I don't need to submit credentials. So what should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Below are two methods to enable RDP without password
(blank password for user account).

**Registry method**

- Run `regedit`
- Position to the key
  *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa*
- Set `LimitBlankPasswordUse` to `0`
  (if not-existent create as DWORD(32 bit))

**Local Group Policy method**

- Run `gpedit.msc`
- Position to
  *Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options.*
- Set
  "Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console login only"
  to Disabled
- Click OK.

Microsoft explains the effect of this policy and registry setting as:

> This security setting determines whether local accounts that are not password protected can be used to log on from locations other than the physical computer console. If enabled, local accounts that are not password protected will only be able to log on at the computer's keyboard.

For more information with screenshots see the article
[How to enable or disable Always Prompt for Password upon Remote Desktop Connection to Windows PC](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-disable-always-prompt-for-password-upon-remote-desktop-connection).

Comment: It still not work, you can see at my 2nd image. What else can I do? Thanks for your answer btw.

Comment: Does [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDnkgUl26M4) help? See also the checks in [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1165904/remote-desktop-connection-your-credentials-didnt-w). Which version of Windows 10 are you using (Home)?

Comment: I reseted Window 10, so may be I lost all of credentials. Now I'm using Window 10 Enterprise 22H2